# Capture URL parameter with requests-mock

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, pytest, requests-mock

I'm using [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io) to mock an external service with a [dynamic response](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#dynamic-response).

The service's URL is something like http://test/containers/test/1234, where `1234` is the object id I want to dynamically generate.

I've tried the regular expression matcher but I don't seem to be able to get the match object in the dynamic response callback.

Is there a way to "capture" that last bit of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to your callback will be the request.  It has a public `path` attribute that you can use:

```
>>> def callback(request, context): 
...     print("request path: ", request.path) 
... 
>>> with requests_mock.Mocker() as m: 
...     m.get("http://test/containers/test/1234", text=callback) 
...     requests.get("http://test/containers/test/1234") 
... 
request path:  /containers/test/1234
```